# Add an autoincrement in a column that is already used as a constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have a column that is used as a FK in an other tables, I wanna try to set Auto_increment value but if fails.

This is what i've tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `m_datos_medicos`.`ficha_identificacion` 
CHANGE COLUMN `ficha_identificacion` `ficha_identificacion` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

This is the error:

> Cannot change column 'ficha_identificacion': used in a foreign key
>   constraint 'fk_ficha_identificacion_has_deporte_ficha_identificacion1'
>   of table 'm_datos_medicos.ficha_identificacion_has_deporte'

How can I set auto_increment value??

Comment: You will need to remove the foreign key index from 'm_datos_medicos.ficha_identificacion_has_deporte' then add the auto increment to `m_datos_medicos`.`ficha_identificacion` then re-add the foreign key index on  'm_datos_medicos.ficha_identificacion_has_deporte'

Comment: thank you, I solved it creating the indexes because  this table has a lot of fk :)